# enabling additional flycheck-checker for spacemacs html layer

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck

I can't seem to enable the `scss-stylelint` checker for `scss-mode`.

`flycheck-verify-setup` gives me this:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer _typography.scss in scss-mode:

  scss-lint (disabled)
    - may enable:         Automatically disabled!
    - executable:         Not found
    - configuration file: Found at "/Users/edbury/.scss-lint.yml"

  scss-stylelint
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /Users/edbury/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/stylelint
    - configuration file: Found at "/Users/edbury/some/path/.stylelintrc.json"

  sass/scss-sass-lint
    - may enable:         Automatically disabled!
    - executable:         Not found
    - configuration file: Not found

  scss
    - may enable: Automatically disabled!
    - executable: Not found

Flycheck Mode is enabled. Use SPC u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.

--------------------

Flycheck version: 32snapshot (package: 20190213.1525)
Emacs version:    26.1
System:           x86_64-apple-darwin17.5.0
Window system:    ns
```

So everything is configured correctly and it's ready to enable. Great! However, when I use `SPC u C-c ! x` to enable checkers, the only one that shows up in the list is `scss-lint`.

Since your input must match a list item, I can't enable `scss-stylelint` via this method.

I thought that my list of `flycheck-checkers` might be incomplete or something, but describing the variable gives me a complete list that includes the stylelint checker:

```
flycheck-checkers is a variable defined in ‘flycheck.el’.
Its value is
(d-ldc ada-gnat asciidoctor asciidoc c/c++-clang c/c++-gcc c/c++-cppcheck cfengine chef-foodcritic coffee coffee-coffeelint coq css-csslint css-stylelint cwl d-dmd dockerfile-hadolint emacs-lisp emacs-lisp-checkdoc erlang-rebar3 erlang eruby-erubis fortran-gfortran go-gofmt go-golint go-vet go-build go-test go-errcheck go-unconvert go-megacheck groovy haml handlebars haskell-stack-ghc haskell-ghc haskell-hlint html-tidy javascript-eslint javascript-jshint javascript-standard json-jsonlint json-python-json jsonnet less less-stylelint llvm-llc lua-luacheck lua markdown-markdownlint-cli markdown-mdl nix nix-linter opam perl perl-perlcritic php php-phpmd php-phpcs processing proselint protobuf-protoc pug puppet-parser puppet-lint python-flake8 python-pylint python-pycompile python-mypy r-lintr racket rpm-rpmlint rst-sphinx rst ruby-rubocop ruby-reek ruby-rubylint ruby ruby-jruby rust-cargo rust rust-clippy scala scala-scalastyle scheme-chicken scss-lint scss-stylelint sass/scss-sass-lint sass scss sh-bash sh-posix-dash sh-posix-bash sh-zsh sh-shellcheck slim slim-lint sql-sqlint systemd-analyze tcl-nagelfar tex-chktex tex-lacheck texinfo textlint typescript-tslint verilog-verilator vhdl-ghdl xml-xmlstarlet xml-xmllint yaml-jsyaml yaml-ruby)
```

Hopefully, I am missing something incredibly simple. Any insight?

**Update** Using `flycheck-select-checker` will allow me to manually select `scss-stylelint`. However, no linting occurs. I do get an error `node: No such file or directory [env]`, which seems odd because `flycheck-verify-setup` returns the all clear.

**Double Update** This only happens in the GUI application. Running `emacs` in `-nw` resolves the issue; however, in GUI, running `M-: (executable-find "node")` does return the correct path (which matches `flycheck-verify-setup`).

**Triple Update** Even using `flycheck-set-checker-executable`, the binary can be located and set successfully, but the GUI app still returns the "not found" error.

**Context** I am using `nvm`, but the path correctly shows in `exec-path`. Clearly, `flycheck` is able to locate the executable, so something else is going on.

Comment: Have you read [this paragraph](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/troubleshooting.html#flycheck-cant-find-any-programs-in-gui-emacs-on-macos) on flycheck's troubleshooting page?

Comment: `brew install npm && npm install stylelint stylelint-scss` and adding `~/node_modules/.bin/stylelint` to the path _worksforme_.

Comment: Also _worksforme_ via `nvm`.

Comment: @nega as mentioned above, both executables are installed and `flycheck` can locate them (evidenced via `flycheck-verify-setup`), `exec-path` includes my `nvm` paths, and `M-: (executable-find "node")` returns the correct path as well. still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of experimentation, I found that (for my setup), I had to skip over `exec-path` and set `PATH` directly via:

`(setenv "PATH" (format "%s:%s" "/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin" (getenv "PATH")))`

The relevant paths to `node` were being found in `exec-path` and `M-: (executable-find "node")` was working fine, but - without updating `PATH` directly - `flycheck` couldn't find the library.

Answer (score 0):

In the output of `flycheck-verify-setup` notice

> Flycheck Mode is enabled. Use SPC u C-c ! x **to enable disabled checkers**.

According to your `flycheck-verify-setup` scss-stylelint is enabled, so it won't be in the list of disabled checkers.

Comment: It "may" be enabled, but is not currently the selected checker. `scss` and `sass/scss-sass-lint` similarly do not show up on the list despite being disabled and in `flycheck-checkers`.

Comment: What happens when you load up some scss with errors in it?

Comment: GUI: I get an error "node: No such file or directory [env]", which seems odd because `flycheck-verify-setup` returns the all clear. || Terminal: lints code

Comment: @nega: I have the same problem with python-flake8: it is disabled and cannot be enabled. Spacemacs say ```C-c !``` is undefined, and ```SPC u``` is transformed to ```C-u```. There is a note in documentation about ```SPC u``` not working, but the workaround suggested does not do the job.